# How to differentiate "+" and +

Tags: regex

I am trying to make a simple lexical analyzer for JISP where the content is:

```
["+", 1, 2]
```

Which is basically a simple addition operation. The problem is that the plus sign must be recognized as a valid addition token only if it is surrounded by quotation marks.

Hence `"+"` is a valid token
while `+` is not a valid token

I tried to recognize this token with simply `"+"  printf("tADD")` in the flex file. However, this expression recognizes both `"+"` and `+` as valid addition tokens. How can I accept `"+"` as a valid token while not recognizing `+` as a valid token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the quotes:

```
"\"+\""  printf("tADD")
```